# How to fix 'unresolved overloaded function type?'

Tags: c++

This is the class

```
class Channel
{
    public:
        Channel(int channelNumber, ChannelType channelType);
};
```

and this is the map

```
map<int, Channel> m_Channel(int, ChannelType);
```

Why does attempting to add a `Channel` to the map like this

```
m_Channel[channelNumber] = Channel(channelNumber, channelType);
```

cause this compile error?

> error: invalid types `‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’` for
>   array subscript

`int` seems like a perfectly valid type for an array subscript.

Comment: Your title and your error do not match.  Which one is the problem?  Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: Does your class have a copy or move constructor? You need one of those for a `map` of *any* kind.

Comment: `m_Channel` is a member object or function? Because this is not a valid construction.

Comment: `Channel` needs a default constructor and move assignment operator (minimally) to be used that way.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for that edit.  Makes it a lot more clear.  Most vexing parse issue.

Comment: @MarkRansom I have no copy constructor. Didn't think it was needed when the key was an `int.` First time using map. I'll add a copy constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver Seems like most vexing parse is irrelevant, just mixing of members and methods/functions.

Comment: As a side note (and I suspect this is an issue in your code base): Naming conventions matter. And they are all good as long as you stick by them, and as long as you apply vastly different conventions to different concepts. A member function is vastly different from a member variable. Don't us the same naming convention for both.

Comment: And... m_Channel is a member, not a function. Using `map<int, Channel> m_Channel;` as @0x5453 suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
map<int, Channel> m_Channel(int, ChannelType);
```

declares a function named `m_Channel` that takes an `int` and a `ChannelType` and returns a `map<int, Channel>`.  I assume you want it to be a member variable instead.

```
map<int, Channel> m_Channel;
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 1):

`map<int, Channel> m_Channel(int, ChannelType);`

if a function declaration, it has two arguments `int`, and `ChannelType`, return a `map<int, Channel>`

you might need just a map like `map<int, Channel> m_Channel`

and this need default constructor of class `Channel`

so you should have

```
class Channel {
public:
    Channel(int channelNumber, ChannelType channelType);
    Channel() {}
};
```

Comment: Note it's the expression `m_Channel[channelNumber]`, not the `map` by itself, that requires a default constructor for `Channel`.

Comment: ... and it seems wrong to add a default constructor here. What are the type's semantics without those two constructor arguments?